# django-filter and aggregate functions

Tags: python, django, filter, aggregate

This is an app specific question: [django-filter](https://github.com/alex/django-filter), here is a brief explanation for those who have not used it.

```
f = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())
```

This line does all the filtering for us. `ProductFilter` is a class, we have specified with filters (forms-alike class). `f` is a filter object (basically items we have asked for), which acts similar to a list.

Now, I'd like to perform `aggregate` functions (like `Avg` for instance) on this `f` object. Do you have any ideas how/if this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Avg


class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    ...

    @property
    def avg(self):
        qs = super(ProductFilter, self).qs

        return qs.aggregate(Avg('price'))['id__avg']
```

So you're adding your own filter property and use it like this in your template:

```
{{ filter.avg }}
```

Comment: You nailed it! Thx again