# Sum of fields for filtered queryset using django_filters

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I have the following view

```
class AuthorList(FilterView):
    model = Author
    filterset_class = AuthorFilter
    context_object_name = 'authors'
```

In the template, one of the field is `{{ author.value }}`, which is an integer.

What I would like to do is to show the sum of all `{{ author.value }}` in my template, but in a dynamic way (if some filters are used, the sum is updated with the current Queryset).

I have tried adding extra context with `get_context_data` but I couldn't find out how to make it in a dynamic way.

**EDIT**

tried this, still not working:

```
    @property
    def get_sum_values(self):
        sum_values = self.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('value'))['value__sum']
        return sum_values
```

and in the template: `{{ authors.get_sum_values }}`

I have also tried to add a print statement in the property, but nothing shows up, so I guess the function is not even loaded.

my models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    value = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, from `self` in `get_sum_values` you reach the instance of the model which has no `objects` attribute. You can try using a [proper query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet) in the `get_context_data()` [method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) of the view.

Comment: Yes that's what I tried first, but  I had `Author.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('value'))['value__sum']`, which was not dynamic (the sum didn't update as the Authors where filtered)

Comment: You should post some code to make clear how the Authors are filtered and what do you mean "dynamic". Meaning, based on the code you provide, you should show the result you get along with the result you want to get.

Comment: I found the use of qs from this link helpful:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964002/django-filter-and-aggregate-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964002/django-filter-and-aggregate-functions)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing the sum in the model as a function ?

```py
@property
def wallet_amount_guests(self):

    data_payments = self.user.earnings_set.filter(transaction_type='g').aggregate(Sum('amount'))['amount__sum']

    if data_payments == None:
        data_payments = 0

    return data_payments
```

The above is just an example I have used before. You can then call in the html as blah.function_name

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my post with your suggestion, but nothing shows up in the template, can you see why?

Comment: Show me you models please ?

Comment: Try the following: @property
    def get_sum_values(self):
        sum_values = self.author_set.all().aggregate(Sum('value'))['value__sum']
        return sum_values

Comment: Also:  @property def get_sum_values(self): sum_values = self.user.author_set.all().aggregate(Sum('value'))['value__sum'] return sum_values